# Значение и происхождение слова "надысь"

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Похоже на значение "на днях", но при чём здесь "дысь"?

Answer (score 1):

День - слово праславянское, оно восходит к индоевропейскому*din= *di(светить, сиять) + суфф. -n-/ -en (как олень, кремень).

Получается, что дись, дысь-древние корни слова "день"

по Далю:

НАДЫСЬ - говоры: ногдысь, анадысь, номнясь, ономня, онамедни; недавно, незадолго, считая не часами, а днями (оными дни);

НАМЕДНИ, намеднись, намесь, намеднича нареч.

Намеднишний - недавний, на днях бывший.

онодась, оно(г)дысь, оногоднись, онолды, онолдысь, онолдась, ономня, ономнясь, ономедни - всё это же в разных говорах.

Даве относится к тому же дню.

Comment: "Даве относится к тому же дню". Может, даве**ча?**

Comment: *Получается, что дись, дысь-древние корни слова "день"* - если так, и это принять за этимологическое обоснование "анадысь", то надо признать и то, что это анадысь прямо восходит к и-е морфу.. Как-то не верится, что оно сохранилось в первозданной чистоте, не трансформировавшись и  не оставив более близких родственников из не столь далекой эпохи - если не на русском, то хотя бы на славянском уровне. Боюсь, что тут или вторичное сближение, или что вероятнее - обычное переосмысление неясной этимологии. Суффикс ысь - это да, тут сомнений нет.

Comment: >> *"Даве относится к тому же дню". Может, давеча?* Это одно и то же. Но не обязательно к тому же дню, просто "недавно". Сам слышал от многих бабок-дедок.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё похоже на церковно-славянское "днесь", которое вроде как сокращение от "день сей". Не знаю, насколько это научно, но во всяком случае логично, получается что-то вроде "на днях сих (сиих)": "надысь".

Comment: Откуда вы взяли, что "днесь" означает "день сей"? По смыслу *днесь* — *сегодня, сейчас* (наречие).